# Given n ordered sets, each containing 6 numbers, generate the next set in the sequence

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I am facing the following problem in machine learning. Given `n` ordered sets, each containing 6 numbers, generate the next set in the sequence. The numbers in a set are not random.
For instance, it could be that these numbers are generated by an equation, e.g. $(1+x^y)$ so that the form the following sequence:

```py
[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 5, 10, 17, 26}, {1, 2, 9, 28, 65, 126}, ..., {1, 2, 1 + 2**n, 1 + 3**n, 1 + 4**n, 1 + 5**n}]
```

But this equation or any other rule governing the order is not known. We are given a large `n` of these sets. What would be the most appropriate way to predict this in Keras?

Comment: one remark - $y$ should be included in every input sequence because it would be impossible for algorithm to figure out that some hidden variable is changing for each sequence (maybe it could figure it out only for arithmetic sequences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should just be a sequence prediction problem, and a multivariate one. You can use LSTMs or GRUs in Keras to handle the sequences. In the simplest architecture, the inputs will be batches of (it seems) n-1 steps of 6 numbers, and the output will be the final 6 numbers in the sequence. This is pretty much how any RNN works. The loss will be `mean_squared_error`, I presume.

But given how much is unknown here about the distribution of the sequences, it's unclear whether this simple approach would work well, or whether even a more complex network can learn whatever patterns these follow.